# In Google Analytics how to distinguish session count user wise

Tags: google-analytics

I have enabled userId feature in Google Analytics. 
On Login page i am setting userId. and also on other pages which user visits after login.

**Problem**: 

User A logs In

User A logs out

User B logs(in same browser session)

User B logs out

User A logs in again logs( In same browser session)

User A log out

In user explorer report for above scenario in google analytics, Count of sessions for user A and B is 1 and 1 respectively.

And also, User A session duration includes the timing of user B' session duration

**Expected**: 

user A should have 2 sessions count and user B should have one.

Do I need to do something when user logs out?

I have also tried by statrting new session explicitly when user logs in, But related custom dimensions are not set in that case.
To start new session i have used this link [Is it possible to manually end a Google Analytics Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647713/is-it-possible-to-manually-end-a-google-analytics-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ga('send', 'pageview', { 'sessionControl': 'end' });`

Written this code on logout event. this will forcefully end session of the user and custom dimensions data is also preserved